# Collection Like Dictionary<K, V> That allows Value Change

Tags: c#, dictionary

I understand why there isn't a method built in to do this, however I want a collection object that will allow Value change *possibly* during Enumeration.

Imagine the following:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> test =  new Dictionary<string, List<string>> {{"key", null}};
```

Lets say I have 20 of these within a class which implements IEnumberable

I'd like to use lambda or a simple `foreach` to iterate through the class and find the object matching a key, then store my `List<T>` with the Value parameter.

Comment: Have you tried using ConcurrentDictionary?

Comment: What's wrong with `if(test.ContainsKey("key"))test["key"] = myList;`? Why do you want to enumerate it?

Comment: Do you mean 20 dictionary-like objects, or 20 `string`/`List<string>` pairs? If the latter, why do you want to iterate through the pairs rather than access the one you want directly by the key?

Comment: Thanks everyone, Tim I didn't think you'd be able to write it like, I was looking for a method of some description :). Time to look at writing the lookup part in lambda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for a collection called [multimap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10089931/880990) for my implementation of it.

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid using an enumerator altogether, e.g.

```
var data = myEnumerable.ToArray();
for(var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++) {
    // here you can manipulate data[i] to your heart's content
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered you can't change a `DictionaryEntry` through the `Value` property - you have to go through the `Item` accessor using the `Key`.

One option is to turn your `Where` results to an array then loop to get the matching `Key`s:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> test =  new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
                                             {{"key", null}};
test.Add("newKey",null);

var matches = test.Where(di => di.Key == "key").ToArray();

foreach(var di in matches) {
    test[di.Key] = new List<string> {"one","two"};
```

Comment: But why not just do `if (test.ContainsKey("key")) test["key"] = new List<string>{...}`?

Comment: @Rawling because the OP mentioned using a Lambda to find the matching keys.  If it's just a simple string match then yes it could be simplified.

Comment: Eh, fair enough. It's a pretty confusing question.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this to modify a value in a dictionary:

```
public static void ChangeValue(string indexKey,List<string> newValue)
{
     if (test.ContainsKey(indexKey))
         keysDictionary[indexKey] = newValue;
}
```