# add to C# dictionary: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection'

Tags: c#

I have a source of data which contains 3 different values like below,

```
List<Configuration> lst = new List<Configuration>
        {
            new Configuration{Name="A", Config="X", Value="1"},
            new Configuration{Name="A", Config="X", Value="2"},
            new Configuration{Name="B", Config="Y", Value="2"}
        };

 public class Configuration
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Config { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Here I want to iterate to the entire source and want to keep "Name" value as a KEY and "Config" & "Value" into a "NameValueCollection".

For this I am taking a dictionary like below,

```
var config = new Dictionary<string, NameValueCollection>();
```

But while adding to this dictionary I m encounter 2 issues,

```
foreach(var c in lst)
        {
            config.Add(c.Name, new NameValueCollection { c.Config, c.Value });
        }
```

1. Duplicate key (Name="A")
2. this line giving error, new NameValueCollection { c.Config, c.Value });

**Note - I want both 1 and 2 for X (in case of of duplicate key)**

Is there any better C# collection or how to resolve above error.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect to see if there is duplicate keys? Both 1 and 2 for X? Or maybe latest value? We don't know

Comment: yes, both 1 and 2 for X

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10089850/c-sharp-dictionary-how-to-add-multiple-values-for-single-key

Comment: I am curious to know what kind of problem are you trying to solve with this NameValueCollection approach. It seems that your first data structure (`List<Configuration>`) is a lot better for many tasks

Comment: I don't have direct data like "List<Configuration>", NameValueCollection is for some other purpose (where we have duplicate key X and their value 1 & 2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
        List<Configuration> lst = new List<Configuration>
        {
            new Configuration{Name="A", Config="X", Value="1"},
            new Configuration{Name="A", Config="X", Value="2"},
            new Configuration{Name="B", Config="Y", Value="2"}
        };
        var config = new Dictionary<string, NameValueCollection>();
        NameValueCollection temp = new NameValueCollection();
        foreach (var c in lst)
        {
            if(config.TryGetValue(c.Name, out temp)){
                config[c.Name].Add(c.Config,c.Value);
            }
            else{
                config.Add(c.Name, new NameValueCollection { {c.Config,c.Value } });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is inefficient. A dictionary is very effficient if you lookup keys. But you use the collection that is returned from the `Keys` property. This property fills a collections with all keys. Then `config.Keys.Contains(c.Name)` compares all strings in this collection with the given name which is `O(n)`. So you lose the lookup performance of the dictionary. Instead use `config.TryGetValue`

Comment: Thank you @TimSchmelter ! :)

Comment: the body of your `if` is incorrect, it must be: `config[c.Name].Add(c.Config, c.Value);`. But even better is: `temp.Add(c.Config, c.Value)` to avoid another lookup

Answer (score 6):

You can use dictionary of [lookups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (it represents a collection where key is mapped to multiple values):

```
var config = lst.GroupBy(cfg => cfg.Name)
                .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, 
                              g => g.ToLookup(cfg => cfg.Config, cfg => cfg.Value));
```

Type of config will be

```
Dictionary<string, ILookup<string, string>>
```

Accessing values:

```
config["A"]["X"] // gives you IEnumerable<string> with values ["1","2"]
```

Comment: But i thought OP wants to use a `NameValueCollection` as value. I'm also missing explanations what's wrong with this approach

Comment: @TimSchmelter I thought OP is asking whether there is a better collection to use :)

Comment: I've overlooked the sentence, but i guess he was looking for a "better" collection because of the error which we can help to fix

Comment: @TimSchmelter there is an "or" conjunction in the question - *Is there any better C# collection or how to resolve above error.* :) so... I have chosen the first part to answer

Answer (score 2):

A [`NameValueCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection(v=vs.110).aspx) contains multiple names and values, because its a collection. So you can't iniialize it in your way. But you can use it  to group all duplicate `Name`s into the same collection. I'd use [`Dictionary<k,v>.TryGetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var config = new Dictionary<string, NameValueCollection>();

foreach (Configuration c in lst)
{
    NameValueCollection nvc;
    if(!config.TryGetValue(c.Name, out nvc))
    {
        nvc = new NameValueCollection();
        config.Add(c.Name, nvc);
    }
    nvc.Add(c.Config, c.Value);
}
```

Comment: Is `TryGetValue` more efficient than `ContainsKey`?  Why not just `if(!config.ContainsKey(c.Name))`?

Comment: Because you need to lookup it again if you want to add a new item to the NameValueCollection.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
in Dictionary class no need to check the value is duplicate or not;
if its the firs time will be add.
if is second time it will be update.

```
   List<Configuration> lst = new List<Configuration>
    {
        new Configuration{Name="A", Config="X", Value="1"},
        new Configuration{Name="A", Config="X", Value="2"},
        new Configuration{Name="B", Config="Y", Value="2"}
    };
        var config = new Dictionary<string, NameValueCollection>();
        foreach (var c in lst)
        {
            config[c.Name] = new NameValueCollection { { c.Config, c.Value } };

        }
```